# Altering php.ini doesn't seem to have effect

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

I am running a webserver with the following configuration:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- PHP 5.5.9
- PHP-FPM
- Nginx

When I upload a file in a Symfony application I am getting the error `The file is too large. Allowed maximum size is 2 MiB.`. I already altered the maxFileSize annotation in the entity but the problem seems to rely in the server configuration.

If I run phpinfo() it returns me the following path to my php.ini: `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`

In this php.ini I have changed the following settings:

`upload_max_filesize = 8M`
`post_max_size = 8M`

Then I restarted php-fpm (service php-fpm restart) but the changes don't appear on the phpinfo page because it still says: `upload_max_filesize 2M`.

Do I miss something?

Comment: run also `service nginx reload` or `service nginx restart`

Comment: I did, but the result is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. It seems that stopping PHP-FPM is quite tricky. Looking further on Serverfault I found that some people had to kill all PHP-FPM processes manually:

`sudo pkill php5-fpm`
`sudo service php5-fpm start`

This worked for me.